# Problems setting Jetty class path using <Set name="extraClasspath">

Tags: configuration, jetty, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have an external jar that I don't want to have bundled with my webapp. I'm putting it on jetty's classpath. Unfortunately, the environment in which I'm deploying is very restrictive and I can only write to two directories: the one that contains contexts and the one that contains the webapps.

I've chosen to have my external jar in the webapp directory. In order to have it visible to my webapp, I'm configuring the WebAppContext to see this additional jar. This is my myAppContext.xml file

```
<Configure id="myContext" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Set name="contextPath">/myApp</Set>
<Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/myApp.war</Set>
<Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
<Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/myExternalJAR.jar</Set>
<New class="com.mycompany.mypackage.MyExternalClass"></New>
```

The last line tries to instantiate MyExternalClass that can be found in my external jar. When starting jetty I get a ClassNotFoundException at this very line of the config file.

Is there something I'm missing? According to the spec, this should work. I would be very grateful for any advice on how to deal with this.

Comment: did you manage to get it running? where do you put this file?